# Will $.when not bother with a deferred AJAX object if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Just wondering before I start hacking away with my code. For example:

```
if (blahblah) {
  $.ajax("randomthingy1");
}
if (blahblahblah) {
  $.ajax("randomthingy2");
}
// Use jQuery to test when they've both finished. Obviously they won't always both finish, as they might not both exist, and none of them might exist either.

$.when($.ajax("randomthingy1"), $.ajax("randomthingy2"), function (stuff) {
  // foo
}

// Might produce an error, as one might not exist. But will it move on and not bother?
```

Just wondering. And if it does bother to create an error and stop execution, is there a way to catch the error and continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.when()` will only fire the `done() handler` if all *Defered* objects you passed in could get *resolved*. So in your instance, if one *Ajax request* fails for whatever reason, the mixed in *Defered* object will resolve to *fail* and your handlers bound through `.when() -> done` will not fire. But of course all your handlers bound to `fail` or `always` will fire in that case.

```
$.when( $.ajax({}), $.ajax({}) )
   .done(function() {
      // all promises (ajax requests) resolved successfully
   })
   .fail(function() {
      // at least one promise (ajax request) failed
   })
   .always(function() {
      // will always get fired
   });
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but here's how I deal with these kind of things:

```
var requests = [];
if (blahblah) {
  requests.push( $.ajax("randomthingy1") );
}
if (blahblahblah) {
  requests.push( $.ajax("randomthingy2") );
}
$.when.apply( $, requests ).then( function( ) {
  // handle success
}, function( ) {
  // handle error
});
```

This makes sure that the code will enter handler even if none of these conditions are satisfied, i.e. requests do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this layout to ensure you always respond to the deferred finishing, whether or not if was resolved or rejected:

```
$.when(deferred1, deferred2, ...)
    .done(function (data1, data2, ...) {
        // success handlers - fires if all deferreds resolve
    })
    .fail(function (error1, error2, ...) {
        // failure handlers - fires if one or more deferreds reject or throw exceptions
    })
    .always(function () {
        // complete handlers - always fires after done or fail
    });
```